# How to open activity from fragment

Tags: android

I am just learning programming and faced with such an error. I need to open activity ruki from home fragment. But when I run the emulator, my application crashes
What am I doing wrong

```
    ImageButton ruki;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
      final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view. findViewById(R.id.ruki);
      View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              switch (view.getId()){
                  case R.id.ruki:
                      Intent intent = new Intent( HomeFragment.this.getActivity(), ruki_activity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      break;
              }
          }
      };
      ruki.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are never initiating `ImageButton ruki;`, you are obtainging reference to `final ImageButton imageButton`, which isn't even used. `ruki.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);` will cause `NullPointerException` (ALWAYS post exception stacktrace)

instead of creating new variable

```
final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view. findViewById(R.id.ruki);
```

just attach result of `findViewById` to declared one

```
ruki = (ImageButton) view. findViewById(R.id.ruki);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(),UsingBackKey.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```